# Draw pyramid inside a cube

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

I'm trying to draw a "transparent" cube (with only edges) and place a pyramid inside this cube, the problem is that the edges of the cube are drawing over pyramid when I rotate it.

Here is an example

[image]

I understand why this is happening (because I draw pyramid first and then a cube), but I want that these edges to not be drawn over the pyramid when this is not needed.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QOpenGLWindow>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QTimer>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#   include <QDebug>
#endif

class MainWindow: public QOpenGLWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();

private:
    QOpenGLContext *m_context;
    QTimer m_timer;
    GLfloat m_angle;

private slots:
    void rotate();

protected:
    void initializeGL() override;
    void paintGL() override;

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow():
    QOpenGLWindow(),
    m_angle(0.0f)
{
    QSurfaceFormat sf;

    sf.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
    sf.setVersion(2, 1);

    setFormat(sf);
    setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);
    create();

    m_context = new QOpenGLContext();
    m_context->setFormat(sf);
    m_context->create();
    m_context->makeCurrent(this);

    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(rotate()));

    m_timer.start(33);
}

void MainWindow::rotate()
{
    m_angle += 0.5f;

    if (m_angle >= 360.0f) {
        m_angle = 0.0f;
    }

    update();
}

void MainWindow::initializeGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}

void MainWindow::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(m_angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glScalef(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);

        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);

        // bottom
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glEnd();

    // The cube (only edges)

    glScalef(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    paintGL();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.resize(480, 480);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is your projection matrix set to identity? If not, what's it set to? Do you ask for a depth buffer when creating a context?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] to answer the questions by @HolyBlackCat Adduming that the GL libs are available is of course fine for that.

Comment: I've edited the question and added full source code (except of *.pro file).

Comment: What's with projection matrix not being set? Also, depth butter is not enabled there.. Note that default z-test function assumes that z-axis  directed AWAY from camera. there are also artifact issues with using GL_LINE and depth buffer.  Fixed pipeline never was updated to address that.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The depth test is enabled in `initializeGL`, the default depth test function is `GL_LESS` - See [`glDepthFunc`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthFunc.xhtml). The matrics of the fixed function matrix stack are initialized by the identity matrix, by default. We can "see" that the geometry is proper drawn in the screenshot. I assume that `initializeGL` is called because face culling is enabled (screenshot). Probably there is no depth buffer, but I can guess only.

Comment: @Rabbid76 `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` enables depth test func, not writing to depth test buffer. `glDepthMask` does that, but usually  implementations have that one enabled by default (unless Qt messed with it, which possible). Thing is that GL_LINES used slightly different depth calculation than polygns, this might be the case.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Initially depth buffer writing is enabled - [`glDepthMask`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthMask.xhtml). This is guaranteed by the specification. In this case the depth is not slightly different, it is completely different. The lines are not the edges of the pyramid, the lines form a cube which surrounds the pyramid.

Comment: @Rabbid76 the thing is that problem  OP describes is not reproduceable on desktop system with fully  compliant compatibility profile :P it's either artifact of depth test or something is off the specification

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, I agree, but In general the code is correct and should work fine, if the depth buffer is set up.

Comment: @Rabbid76, @Swift-FridayPie, Thanks to your comments I found that I did not set depth buffer size, so I added line `sf.setDepthBufferSize(24)` (not sure about what size it should be set) after that I got vice-versa behavior, take a look at this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/JSfWgUx

It seems like the front edges behave like back edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally done it:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow():
    QOpenGLWindow(),
    m_angle(0.0f)
{
    QSurfaceFormat sf;

    sf.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
    sf.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    sf.setVersion(2, 1);

    setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);
    setFormat(sf);
    create();

    m_context = new QOpenGLContext(this);
    m_context->setFormat(sf);
    m_context->create();
    m_context->makeCurrent(this);

    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(rotate()));

    m_timer.start(33);
}

void MainWindow::rotate()
{
    m_angle += 0.5f;

    if (m_angle >= 360.0f) {
        m_angle = 0.0f;
    }

    update();
}

void MainWindow::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepth(-1.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_GEQUAL);
}

void MainWindow::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // The Pyramid

    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(m_angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glScalef(0.33f, 0.33f, 0.33f);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
       // Front
       glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
       glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

       // Back
       glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
       glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

       // Left
       glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
       glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

       // Right
       glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
       glVertex3f(0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
       glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
       glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

       // Bottom
       glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glEnd();

    // The Cube (edges)

    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(m_angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        // Front
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        // Back
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Left
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);

        // Right
        glVertex3f(1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    paintGL();
}
```

Probably this solution is far from ideal, but it does exactly what I need (any tips would be appreciated).

demo image

[image]

I'd like to thank @Swift - Friday Pie and @Asaq for such detailed answers which helped me a bit more to understand how opengl works.

If anyone is interested - I'm on Linux (Fedora 28), graphic card is Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2).

Answer (score 0):

> ... after that I got vice-versa behavior, take a look at this screenshot It seems like the front edges behave like back edges.

The triangles of your pyramid are set clockwise, but default, counterclockwise polygons are taken to be front-facing. Set [`glFrontFace(GL_CW)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml) or change the order of `glVertex3f`.

> Could someone explain me why triangle is rendering over quad please ?

When [Depth Testing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) is active, the fragments will be displayed depending on their depth. The depth value from the fragment is compared to the depth value from the matching sample currently in the framebuffer. The conditional test is specified by the function [`glDepthFunc`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthFunc.xhtml). The initial value of `glDepthFunc` is `GL_LESS`.

In your example the depth of the triangle's fragments is LESS than that of the quad's fragments, so the triangle is over the quad.

[image]

Comment: A wrong winding order won't explain why **all** the lines are in front of the polygons. The questioner found the solution hisself (see the last comment to the question - *"I found that I did not set depth buffer size, so I added line `sf.setDepthBufferSize(24)` ..."*'

Comment: Actually it solved one problem and created second (see screenshot in my previous comment). Still don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `glFrontFace(GL_CW)` doesn't help (it only got worse), also I googled pyramid examples with correct order of vertices (hope they are correct) but got same result.

Comment: On 2nd screenshot the front edge is what is drawn above the pyramid (check it, use color), but the pyramid is not drawn correctly. Before the answer, I compiled your code. Without `glFrontFace(GL_CW)`, I saw the 2nd screenshot and the [correct pyramid with it](https://imgur.com/a/TzPsJn1).

Comment: I did a very basic example https://pastebin.com/cDGi4Sgh , https://imgur.com/a/cnNGR0f  . Could someone explain me why triangle is rendering over quad please ?

Comment: @neversleep see answer

Comment: @neversleep: because it's closer. Default depth test function value GL_LESS means that if Z is _less_ then depth test is successful, i.e. triangle is closer. z for trianle in that example is 0.9, for quad it is 1.0.  Z axis directed away from projection plane with identity. You really want to try control projection if you want more obvious results. Among all other things you don't really want to work {1...-1, 1...-1, 1...0} float space, it's too small of value ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Setting minimal depth buffer didn't changed anything for me (likely because platform setting was already 24, but  checking those defaults is not without merit). The problem is that displayed order of cube's edges still look wrong: the edge that supposed to be closer is painted over by pyramid.

[image]

Because you don't do anything about visibility of edges it causes illusion that cube must be rotating in direction opposite and perpendicular to rotation of pyramid.

The problem is that it's pyramid which is actually wrong. Let me prove that:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);//(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
glEnd();
```

Resulting image is:

[image]

Cube rotates in *supposed* direction, it isn't inside out. That means that pyramid is. One reason of that is that we actually see *back* faces, not front ones.

If I convert your code to emulate transparent pyramid, , but save default culling settings:

```
void MainWindow::initializeGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

/*...*/

    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f);

        glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);

        glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.3f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f);

        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);

        // bottom
        glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.3f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glEnd();
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.6f);

        glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.6f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);

        glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.6f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.6f);

        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);

        // bottom
        glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.6f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glEnd();
```

I get image

[image]

I still see how pyramid rotates,  all of its edges and that  line of cube that is "behind" is clipped (because blending does nothing to depth test).

But now if you look at the "bold" faces of pyramid - I intentionally made faces that are invisible without blending bold by giving them larger alpha value - you'll see that they rotate properly, in same direction as cube does. That means that your mesh, the pyramid, is actually inverted, "inside out". With non-convex figures that would be more obvious, with convex ones that creates illusion of opposite rotation.

All you should do is change order of vertices or switch to GL_CW for pyramid (GL_CCW is default).
[image]

I surmise that this is expected look of the pyramid, if the face colors are taken in account. If it isn't, that means that you assumed that vertices with greater Z-coordinate is further away from projection plane. With Identity projection matrix and GL_LESS depth test function it's opposite. Be advised, if you switch direction of only one axis, that literally inverts all rules that related to direction of rotation, counterclockwise becomes clockwise.

NB: Trick I used for transparency illusion doesn't work that well with non-convex figures. Why? To use color blending you have to draw faces in order of their depth test doing this manually. My dirty trick does draw all faces twice, but culling removes those which face camera during first pass, and removes those which face away during second pass. For non-convex that doesn't match the order - there are faces that face camera but are further away than some "hidden" ones, wrong order. More work is required. Usage of flexible pipeline really changes how OpenGL can handle this.